# prove that the sequence $\{\cos(\frac{\pi n}{3})\}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

proof:

for all $a \in R$, if $ε=\frac{1}{4}$, then for all $n \in N$ either $|\cos(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{3})-a|≥\frac{1}{4}$ or $|\frac{\pi(n+2)}{3}-a|≥\frac{1}{4}$. Therefore, the sequence $\{\cos(\frac{\pi n}{3})\}$ diverges.

Is this a correct proof? Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: does {x} denote the fractionsl part of x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n = \cos\left( \frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$$

Consider the following:

$$a_{6k}=1$$

$$a_{6k+1}=\frac12 \ne 1$$

We have found two subsequences that converge to different limits, hence it diverges.

Comment: I was going to write $a_{6k}=1$ and$ a_{6k+3} = -1$.